# xamarin.mac add netstandard lib but build error

Tags: xamarin.mac

develop mac application use vs mac.
i can ref a .NET Standard2.0 lib to my xamarin.mac project.
but i can not build success..
the err is :

/Users/yuzd/Projects/AntDeploy/AntDeploy/ViewController.cs(25,25): Error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. (CS0012) (AntDeploy)

how to solve this err?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Stop using `packages.config` and switch to package references.

Comment: i tried but failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [GitHub Issue Here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6552).

Add the following to your MacOS .csproj

> ```
> <Reference Include="netstandard" />
> ```

Comment: thanks , after do add netstandard reference to the project file.i can build success. but when i debug . the netstandard lib load fail:newtonsoft.json dll file not found!

Comment: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16083659/62422889-38068800-b6ec-11e9-82e1-9c5d1de2ed52.png)  ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16083659/62422902-65ebcc80-b6ec-11e9-8e13-ddd39689c907.png)